# How to do the following symbolic substitution?

Tags: replacement

In the algorithm that I am trying to implement, I have the following symbolic substitution to be done  $z^{-2 n} \rightarrow \frac{(i t)^{2 n-1}}{(2n-1)!}  $.
I tried to do the above as

```
sim= z^{-m}:> (It)^(Abs[m]-1)/(Abs[m]-1)!
```

and then substituted the above everywhere needed for eg: `1/z^4/.sim`.

So for eg : $z^{-4}$ term should be substituted with $\frac{(i t)^{3}}{(3)!}$.

But with the above symbolic substitution, I encounter an apparent problem when the expression has 1. Because then it should treat it as $z^{0}$ and do the substitution accordingly, till now I have been resolving it by substituting by hand each time. Is there a better way to do it because as my expressions become more extensive, they become cumbersome?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems:

1. Braces are for lists, and they are not parentheses. Use parentheses `( )` to separate or group operations
2. You need patterns in your left-hand-side expression to represent variable values of the exponent. Otherwise you will only match *exactly* $m$, and not *any number* as you want.
3. Substitution is lexical: `-m` does not match `4` because there is no minus sign in 4. Rewrite your expression to match a simple generic `m` on the left-hand side, then change the signs appropriately in the right-hand side of your rule.

With all that:

```
sim = z^m_ :> It^(Abs[-m] - 1)/(Abs[-m] - 1)!

1/z^4 /. sim

(* Out: It^3/6 *)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. Regarding the second part of my question, is there a way so that when there is just a number, let's say $a$, then it should be treated at $a z^{0}$ and then the necessary substitution for $z^{0}$ is carried forwards.

Comment: @Erosannin If the exponent of $z$ is zero, then your formula would have to calculate $(-1)!$. How do you define that?